# CSS Clear causing space between divs

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of creating a jsp tag that converts table tags to divs. This is the code that my tag generates.  In ie9 there is a space between the blue div and the black div. I've tried just about everything to solve it the correct way. Please help :-(, I included it verbatim because I'm not sure if ie9 does something strange with white space;

```
<!-- AUTO GENERATED TABLE ELEMENT -->
<div style=" ">

<!-- AUTO GENERATED TABLE:ROW ELEMENT -->
<div style="clear:left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

<!-- AUTO GENERATED TABLE:CELL ELEMENT -->
<div style="float:left; background-color: blue; height: 50px; width: 300px; text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <!--<p style="color: white;">You have reached this page in error</p>-->
        </div>
<!-- AUTO GENERATED TABLE:CELL ELEMENT -->

<!-- AUTO GENERATED TABLE:CELL ELEMENT -->
<div style="float:left; background-color: blue; height: 50px; width: 300px; text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <!--<p style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">No matching path</p>-->
        </div>
<!-- AUTO GENERATED TABLE:CELL ELEMENT -->
    </div>
<!-- AUTO GENERATED TABLE:ROW ELEMENT -->

<!-- AUTO GENERATED TABLE:ROW ELEMENT -->
<div style="clear:left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

<!-- AUTO GENERATED TABLE:CELL ELEMENT -->
<div style="float:left; background-color: black; color: white; height: 600px; width: 600px; text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <font style="font-size: 50px">&iquest;</font>
        </div>
<!-- AUTO GENERATED TABLE:CELL ELEMENT -->
    </div>
<!-- AUTO GENERATED TABLE:ROW ELEMENT -->
</div>
<!-- AUTO GENERATED TABLE ELEMENT -->
```

Comment: Do you have a doctype on this page?
Try and remove white space, it may matter
Heck, try clear: both

Comment: @user1538100 I think you might have it with the doctype, I'm still testing but that should fix it. :-)

Comment: @user1538100 Put that as an answer and I will definitely accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look's like your missing a doctype, that will make IE sort itself out.